# How do I lock down a version of CocoaPods for a project?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

How do I lock down the version of CocoaPods used to install pods in a project? I see plenty of discussion on locking down the pod **dependencies**, but not the version of CocoaPods used to install those dependencies.

This would mitigate the problem of `Podfile.lock` changing when each developer on a project uses a different version of CocoaPods.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time we simply update the cocoapods to latest version.
If you got some reasons for keeping the version, you might go with `rvm + bundler + cocoapods` approach.

1. install rvm and set ruby version
2. install bundler to the ruby ver.
3. create and share a Gemfile to your team in project folder

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'cocoapods', '~> 1.9.3'
gem 'fastlane'
```

4. install it
   `bundle install`